# ToArray() function limitation

Tags: c#, arrays, toarray

I am using the `.ToArray()` method to convert my string to `char` array whose size i have kept `char[] buffer = new char[1000000];` but when I am using the following code:

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(path1))
{
    buffer = streamReader.ReadToEnd().ToCharArray();
}
// buffer = result.ToArray();
threadfunc(data_path1);
```

The size of the buffer getting fixed up to 8190, even it is not reading the whole file after using `.ToCharArray()` or `.ToArray()`.
What is the reason for this does `.ToCharArray()` or `.ToArray()` have size limitations? As if I do not use this function I'm able to read whole file in string format, but when trying to convert it into char array by using this function I am getting size limitations.

Comment: Will you try separating the call of `ReadToEnd()` and `ToCharArray()`. (i.e. Put the result of first one in the a string and then call the second on the string.)

Comment: The way you are getting the characters with `ToCharacterArray`... you can declare the array `buffer` without a size and it will be sized to the correct size when read. In other words `char[] buffer;` will work.

Comment: [ToCharArray()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,81c2d980f5d0ee35,references) converts the whole string to a byte array. It does not have a limit on the size of the generated array.

Comment: First of all, whatever you assign to `buffer` before that code is overwritten so the 1MB buffer you allocated is just left for the garbage collector. The question is, how big is the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ToCharArray()` returns new instance of of array. So your `buffer` will refer to the new instance which is the size of data returned by `ReadToEnd`.

If you want keep `buffer` same size just add new array to the existed one

```
char[] buffer = new char[1000000];
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(path1))
{
    var tempArray = streamReader.ReadToEnd().ToCharArray();
    tempArray.CopyTo(buffer, 0);
}
```

If you want just use the result array - you don't need to "predict" the size of array - just use returned one

```
public char[] GetArrayFromFile(string pathToFile)
{
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(path1))
    {
        var data = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    return data.ToCharArray();
}    

var arrayFromFile = GetArrayFromFile(@"..\path.file");
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is the problem is that read to end should finish before you call the `ToCharArray()`. This might help you. You don't need to define buffer since `ToCharArray()` creates a new instance of `char[]` itself.

```
string content;
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(path1))
{
    content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
var buffer = content.ToCharArray();
```

Comment: _should finish before you call the ToCharArray_ - Do you mean that `streamReader.ReadToEnd()` return "not finished" string until reader is disposed?

Comment: Dispose is a super set. you may call `streamReader.Flush()` streams have this bad habit of not finishing the job when their functions return. Just an experience of mine

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using incorrect encoding. By default [StreamReader(String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ke0fzy(v=vs.110).aspx) uses UTF8 encoding:

> The complete file path is specified by the path parameter. This
>   constructor initializes the encoding to UTF8Encoding and the buffer
>   size to 1024 bytes.

Don't pre-allocate the buffer size, unless you have a specific need.

If your file is in ASCII format, you need to update your `StreamReader` constructor:

```cs
char[] buffer = null;

using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(path1, Encoding.ASCII))
{
    buffer = streamReader.ReadToEnd().ToCharArray();
}
// buffer = result.ToArray();
threadfunc(data_path1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your file contain binary data? If it contains EOF character and the stream is opened in text mode (which `StreamReader` does), that character will signal end of file, even if it is not actually the end of the file.

I can reproduce this by reading random .exe files in text mode.